# How would I computationally find a generating functions coefficient?

Tags: algorithms, generating-functions

More specifically $a_n=(1,5,10,25,100,500,1000,2000,10000)$

$G(x)=\Pi_{n=0}^8 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{a_ni}$

So when $a_n=1$ the series = $1+x+x^2+x^3+...$

$a_n=5, 1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+...$

$a_n=10, 1+x^{10}+x^{20}+x^{30}+...$

etc.

Comment: You want a closed form expression for $G$? Or an algorithm that gives you the coefficient of one particular term $x^k$?

Comment: An algorithm that gives the coefficient of some term.  So $x^{10}$ would be 4, $x^{15}$ would be 6

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start.

You want
$G(x)=\Pi_{n=0}^8 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{a_ni}$,
so look at the sums, which are
just geometric series.

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{a_ni}
=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(x^{a_n})^{i}
=\dfrac{1}{1-x^{a_n}}
$

so
$G(x)
=\Pi_{n=0}^8 \dfrac{1}{1-x^{a_n}}
= \dfrac{1}{\Pi_{n=0}^8(1-x^{a_n})}
$.

At this point,
I'd probably expand into partial fractions
or use logarithmic  differentiation
to get something that might enable the
isolation of coefficients.

Sort of reminds me of
Hardy and Ramanujan's stuff.

Comment: I got to $$\dfrac{1}{\Pi_{n=0}^8(1-x^{a_n})}$$ before but i wasn't sure how to precede.  I thought about differentiating it n times for the Taylor expansion of the function but that seemed complicated.  I figured that the expanded series would be easier to work with.  I looked into Cauchy product but I thought there would be an easier way than that.

Would you mind explaining how partial fractions or logarithmic differentiation would isolate the coefficients?